# Create PNR SABRE

Tags: sabre

I am looking to create pnr in sabre for return flight with branded fares. So basically I have 2 different branded PricedItinerary one for onward and other for return and I want to create singe PNR for both this PricedItinerary. How is it possible ? I tired sending brandId in flightsegment. PNR gets created but getting error "

```
{
  "code": "WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE",
  "content": "OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ: NO COMBINABLE FARES FOR CLASS USED"
},
{
  "code": "53",
  "content": "NO COMBINABLE FARES FOR CLASS USED"
}
```

Comment: I guess its because of a wrong combination of booking classes and fares or just plain and simple not combinable fares (e.g. for LH it does not make sense to have a light + classic fare as rules of the light fare apply). Could you please post your request and if possible the according search result? Everything else is pure speculation

Comment: request json is too big to dd here. Not understanding how to add that.

Comment: use pastebin or something similiar - or just cut out the result you are trying to book

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error happens when you are trying to combining non-combinable classes/fares try to use a class/branded more permissive in both segments.
To help you I have to know:

- What is/are the segment/s
- Class/classes sued during the pricing

In a nutshell, post your RQ payload please!

Answer (score 0):

Use This Json Request Replace your PCC And RPH Information

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api- 
crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v2.4.0/passenger/records?mode=create',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
"CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ":{
   "targetCity":"Z01K",
   "haltOnAirPriceError":true,
   "TravelItineraryAddInfo":{
      "AgencyInfo":{
         "Address":{
            "AddressLine":" Your Agency",
            "CityName":"Dhaka",
            "CountryCode":"BD",
            "PostalCode":"1215",
            "StateCountyProv":{
               "StateCode":"BD"
            },
            "StreetNmbr":"Dhaka"
         },
         "Ticketing":{
            "TicketType":"7TAW"
         }
      },
      "CustomerInfo":{
         "ContactNumbers":{
            "ContactNumber":[
               {
                  "NameNumber":"1.1",
                  "Phone":"8801685370455",
                  "PhoneUseType":"H"
               }
            ]
         },
         "PersonName":[
            {
               "NameNumber":"1.1",
               "GivenName":"Fahim",
               "Surname":"Fahim",
               "Infant":false,
               "PassengerType":"ADT",
               "NameReference":""
            }
            
         ]
      }
   },
   "AirBook":{
      "HaltOnStatus":[
         {
            "Code":"HL"
         },
         {
            "Code":"KK"
         },
         {
            "Code":"LL"
         },
         {
            "Code":"NN"
         },
         {
            "Code":"NO"
         },
         {
            "Code":"UC"
         },
         {
            "Code":"US"
         }
      ],
      "OriginDestinationInformation":{
         "FlightSegment":[
            {
                    "DepartureDateTime":"2022-06-30T06:35:00",
                    "ArrivalDateTime":"2022-06-30T12:05:00",
                    "FlightNumber":"713",
                    "NumberInParty":"1",
                    "ResBookDesigCode":"S",
                    "Status":"NN",
                    "OriginLocation":{
                       "LocationCode":"DAC"
                    },
                    "DestinationLocation":{
                       "LocationCode":"IST"
                    },
                    "MarketingAirline":{
                       "Code":"TK",
                       "FlightNumber":"713"
                    }
                 },{
                    "DepartureDateTime":"2022-06-30T13:30:00",
                    "ArrivalDateTime":"2022-06-30T17:15:00",
                    "FlightNumber":"1",
                    "NumberInParty":"1",
                    "ResBookDesigCode":"S",
                    "Status":"NN",
                    "OriginLocation":{
                       "LocationCode":"IST"
                    },
                    "DestinationLocation":{
                       "LocationCode":"JFK"
                    },
                    "MarketingAirline":{
                       "Code":"TK",
                       "FlightNumber":"1"
                    }
                 }

         ]
      },
      "RedisplayReservation":{
         "NumAttempts":10,
         "WaitInterval":300
      }
   },
   "AirPrice":[
      {
         "PriceRequestInformation":{
            "Retain":true,
            "OptionalQualifiers":{
               "FOP_Qualifiers":{
                  "BasicFOP":{
                     "Type":"CASH"
                  }
               },
               "PricingQualifiers":{
                  "PassengerType":[
                     {
                        "Code":"ADT",
                        "Quantity":"1"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "SpecialReqDetails":{
      "SpecialService":{
         "SpecialServiceInfo":{
            "AdvancePassenger":[
               {
                  "Document":{
                     "Number":"BM2004955",
                     "IssueCountry":"BGD",
                     "NationalityCountry":"BGD",
                     "ExpirationDate":"2024-08-09",
                     "Type":"P"
                  },
                  "PersonName":{
                     "NameNumber":"1.1",
                     "GivenName":"Kayes Fahim",
                     "MiddleName":"Fuad",
                     "Surname":"Fahim",
                     "DateOfBirth":"1998-01-11",
                     "Gender":"M"
                  },
                  "SegmentNumber":"A"
               }
            ],
            "SecureFlight":[
               {
                  "PersonName":{
                     "NameNumber":"1.1",
                     "GivenName":"Kayes Fahim",
                     "Surname":"Fuad",
                     "DateOfBirth":"1998-01-11",
                     "Gender":"M"
                  },
                  "SegmentNumber":"A",
                  "VendorPrefs":{
                     "Airline":{
                        "Hosted":false
                     }
                  }
               }                   
            ],
            "Service":[                  
               {
                  "SSR_Code": "OTHS",
                  "Text": "CC Kayes Fahim",
                  "PersonName": {
                     "NameNumber": "1.1"
                  },
                  "SegmentNumber": "1"
               },
               {
                  "SSR_Code": "CTCM",
                  "Text": "Fahim",
                  "PersonName": {
                     "NameNumber": "1.1"
                  },
                  "SegmentNumber": "1"
               },
               {
                  "SSR_Code": "CTCE",
                  "Text": "fahim//flyfarint.com",
                  "PersonName": {
                     "NameNumber": "1.1"
                  },
                  "SegmentNumber": "1"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "PostProcessing":{
      "EndTransaction":{
         "Source":{
            "ReceivedFrom":"API WEB"
         }
      },
      "RedisplayReservation":{
         "waitInterval":100
      }
   }
  }
 }',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Conversation-ID: 2021.01.DevStudio',
'Authorization: Bearer 'your TOken'
),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the same marriage indicators that BFM is returning? Maybe it would help to copy the request that returns this error here (without any confidential data, of course).

Comment: AFAIK marriage indicators are not needed

Comment: Thanks for the support. I was using wrong RBD codes. This is resolved now.

Comment: Post Your Json Request